# iOS - How to be notified when visible (top) view controller is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build a push model to detect visible view controller change in my iOS app.

I know I could have a listener to all `willDidAppear` method or implement similar delegate methods.

For example:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Also, I know I could listen to `UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification`, but not every class is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. So this might not work for me.

I wonder is there any easier and more robust way to achieve the goal?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to listen to all views, right? (abstract the `viewWillAppear` so that they all report to the same delegate)

Answer (score 0):

you can do  this  by add  extension  to UIViewController  and swizzle viewDidLoad method with your own method  so every  time any UIViewController pushed or present your own implementation  of viewDidLoad will be called and you can do any thing you want inside it   also you can swizzle any method not only viewDidLoad 
see this example of how swizzling work

```
extension UIViewController {
// We cannot override load like we could in Objective-C, so override initialize instead
public override static func initialize() {

    // Make a static struct for our dispatch token so only one exists in memory
    struct Static {
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    // Wrap this in a dispatch_once block so it is only run once
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        // Get the original selectors and method implementations, and swap them with our new method
        let originalSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIViewController.myViewDidLoad)

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        // class_addMethod can fail if used incorrectly or with invalid pointers, so check to make sure we were able to add the method to the lookup table successfully
        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    }
}

// Our new viewDidLoad function
// In this example, we are just logging the name of the function, but this can be used to run any custom code
func myViewDidLoad() {
    // This is not recursive since we swapped the Selectors in initialize().
    // We cannot call super in an extension.
    self.myViewDidLoad()
    print("do what you want here") // logs myViewDidLoad()
}
}
```

Comment: Method swizzling is pretty deep, dark mojo, and only works for Objective-C style message passing. It's probably not the best idea for somebody who's just starting out with iOS development.

Comment: @ali : what version of objective-c is that written in ?

Comment: @ Duncan sure it may be not the best idea but he can achieve what he want by using it then he can improve it by using any other way

Comment: @YvesLeBorg it is swift 3 not  objective-c

Comment: @AliAdam Not working in Swift 5. Do you have any idea?